# Electrical Panel in Exterior Wall

Tags: electrical-panel

My (Northern California) 1950s house has its (100A) main breaker panel in the back of the garage wall, above the gas riser and meter, with an access door on the outside:
[image: Text]

As a step towards various upgrades (heat pump, solar, rewire, removing the old panel), I want to install a subpanel on the same wall, over 3' from the gas riser. My preference would be for a similar "cupboard". Can this meet current code? If it can, would the subpanel need to be outdoor rated?

My fall-back to to install an outdoor (North facing wall) semi-flush panel, as this appears to make attaching the existing Romex easier. Thoughts?

As you can see, the current panel is rather full (not to mention messy), and appears to be indoor rated. There is currently one subpanel (240V 40A feed) in an accessory building. I'd like to add another (40+ space) that will (eventually) become the main panel to allow for new circuits (bathroom remodels are next, and need more) and gradual rewiring.

As an aside, all the current circuits have ample wire to go to the new subpanel location, but I'm not sure if this would require them to be rewired. I'm fine with adding AFCI breakers where required, but it would be nice if I could just move existing (old NM) circuits.

EDIT: As requested, some photos of the current (GE) panel:
[image: Text]
[image: Text]

Comment: I doubt if  romex would be allowed today outside, even if in a cupboard.  Though the wall directly into the panel is a bit different.  That would not be my number one choice of location for electrical panels/devices.

Comment: Can you get photos of your actual situation please, including closeups of any labeling on your actual main panel?

Comment: Added photos. Add work during my ownership (13 years) was permitted.

Comment: @RogerDIY -- are you OK with everything coming in via the bottom of the new panel?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'd prefer to keep the Romex at the top, including the older NM that currently comes in the side, so am considering a semi-flush panel (e.g. Leviton LG420-BED).

Comment: I do wonder how the cupboard is classified (damp, wet, dry), as, AFAIK, the inside of the garage would be dry, even right next to the door.